# EmberJS: Calling action from child controller

Tags: ember.js

So, basically I have two controllers. One of them has an action that I would like to be able to call from an action within the other controller. I tried something like this:

Controllers:

```
Demoapp.FooController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['bar'],
    actions: {
        fooControllerAction: function() {
            var foo = this.get('controllers.foo');
            foo.set('sendMsg', true);
        }
    }    
});

Demoapp.BarController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    sendMsg: false,
    actions: {
        barControllerMsg: function() {
            console.log("Message from Bar controller");
        }.observes('sendMsg')
    }    
});
```

Template:

```
 <h1>Foo Template</h1>

 <button type="submit" {{action 'fooControllerAction'}}>Call barControllerMsg</button>
```

And it didn't work... I'm not really sure how to go about doing this, can someone offer some advice? The other solution I found involved having a lot of logic in the template and I'd rather avoid that.

Comment: I don't think the observer function should be in the `actions` hash

Comment: Great! I made it an answer. Please accept it so the question doesn't show up as unanswered anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the observer out of the `actions` hash

```
Demoapp.BarController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    sendMsg: false,
    barControllerMsg: function() {
       console.log("Message from Bar controller");
    }.observes('sendMsg')
});
```